# HLLAPI Function 99 not working as expected

Tags: excel, vba, hllapi

I have been trying to screen scrape from IBM's mainframe and I got stuck trying to convert the Row and Col into a position (Function 99). I have tried my best to debug this simple error but I just cannot find what's wrong with it.

```
Debug.Print hllapi(99, "AR", 6, 53)
```

My sessions are connected, everything is working great except the Convert Position or RowCol (99) function I am trying to use. It keeps returning a status code of 9999 which indicates that my data string (i.e. "AR") is not uppercased or the letter P/R does not exist in the second character. ("Character 2 in the data string is not P or R or uppercased").

I have been unable to fix this despite trying all sorts of methods.

Comment: You must have P or R as the second character in Standard EHLLAPI. With Enhanced EHLLAPI the P or R must be at position 5, id: `"A   R"`